# Getting KDE applications to recognize Forward/Back mouse buttons

Tags: kde, mouse

I have a mouse with Forward/Back buttons which work correctly in Firefox, Chrome etc... i.e. they are recognized. They are also seen by `xev` which generates events, e.g.

```
ButtonRelease event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x6200001,
root 0xaf, subw 0x6200002, time 29607818, (36,54), root:(38,108),
state 0x10, button 8, same_screen YES
```

I now want to use them to change virtual desktops when my cursor is pointing at the KDE (Plasma) desktop. However, the "Mouse Actions" parameter at the Plasma desktop settings does not recognize the clicks of those buttons.

Also, Dolphin does not seem to recognize those buttons for forward/back. What am I missing there? I haven't found any related options in the KDE settings.

I'm using x86-64 Arch Linux, if it's relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [use `xbindkeys`](http://hanschen.org/2009/10/13/mouse-shortcuts-with-xbindkeys/) to map the buttons to text that will trigger KDE shortcuts. However, that may interfere with Firefox's recognition of the buttons. You can use [mouse gestures](http://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Shortcuts_and_Gestures#Mouse_Gestures) instead of buttons if that is a concern. Also, you should probably commont on [this feature request to use mouse buttons as KDE shortcuts](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96431).

Comment: This works well enough for the time being.